# Is it really necessary to use removeAuthStateListener in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

In my app, I have implemented Firebase authentication. I have created an `AuthStateListener` to check the state of the user:

```
firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
authStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth auth) {
        FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null) {
            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    }
};
```

In the `onStart()`, I'm using this code:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(authStateListener);
}
```

Is it really necessary to remove the AuthStateListener in the `onStop()`?

```
firebaseAuth.removeAuthStateListener(authStateListener);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't remove every listener that you add, you will leak memory, possibly crash your app, and also cause your app to run slower over time.  It's up to you if you want your app to have a poor experience, but the recommendation is to always remove any listeners when they are no longer useful.

Comment: I'll follow your advice and I'll always remove the listener. Thank you for the explanation!